# How to export AppMaker app as a zip file?

Tags: google-app-maker

I don't have the "export" option from AppMaker menu. Any idea where it could come from ? I'm the owner of the project (I can see this in my Drive).

I have created this project from an existing zip file (of an existing AppMaker project), could it be the reason ?

here what I see

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has moved, while in the project, in the left menu, at the very bottom after all your pages/scripts you have in your project is where you can find it.

[image]